# Add style to button in buttonGroup when user select one of the option

Tags: reactjs, styles

I am trying to add style in button When the user selects one of the button from buttonGroup then button should be highlighted and it should remain highlighted even if user select another button from different button group but in my case When user select another button option from different buttonGroup then previous button lose it’s state and it no longer shows the active highlighted state. can anyone tell me how to achieve that? In my code, I added backgroundColor to style property but doesn't seem to work.

code::

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import Answers from "../Answers/Answers";

class Section extends Component {
    state = {
        que1: "",
        que2: "",
        que3: ""
    };

    handleClick = event => {
        this.setState(
            {
                que1: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
            },
            () => {
                console.log(this.state.que1);
            }
        );
    };

    handleClick2 = event => {
        this.setState(
            {
                que2: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
            },
            () => {
                console.log(this.state.que2);
            }
        );
    };

    handleClick3 = event => {
        this.setState(
            {
                que3: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
            },
            () => {
                console.log(this.state.que3);
            }
        );
    };

    render() {
        let styles = {
            width: '50%',
            margin: '0 auto',
            marginBottom: '15px'
        }
        console.log(this.state);
        const { history } = this.props;
        const { que1, que2, que3 } = this.state;
        return (
            <>
                <p>1. I was stressed with my nerves on edge.</p>
                <Button.Group widths="5" onClick={this.handleClick} style={styles}>
                    <Answers style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray' }} />
                </Button.Group>
                {` `}
                <p>2. I lost hope and wanted to give up when something went wrong.</p>
                <Button.Group widths="5" onClick={this.handleClick2} style={styles}>
                    <Answers style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray' }}/>
                </Button.Group>
                {` `}
                <p>3. I feel very satisfied with the way I look and act</p>
                <Button.Group widths="5" onClick={this.handleClick3} style={styles}>
                    <Answers style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray' }}/>
                </Button.Group>
                <p />
                {` `}
                <Button
                    disabled={!que1 || !que2 || !que3}
                    onClick={() => history.push("/section2")}
                >
                    NEXT
        </Button>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Section);
```

Answers.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

export class Answers extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Button data-key="Never">Never</Button>
        <Button data-key="Occassionally">Occassionally</Button>
        <Button data-key="Often">Often</Button>
        <Button data-key="Very Often">Very Often</Button>
        <Button data-key="Always">Always</Button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Answers;
```

output :

[image]

Comment: I think I see your problem - its this: https://codesandbox.io/s/wzq0941wol - working on a solution for you..

Comment: You mean you are working on this solution ?

Comment: Im looking into it - can you post your Answers class above?

Comment: ok sure I am posting

Comment: I posted my answer class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your Button.Group components are not aware of the stored state values (que1, que2, que3). I believe you need to pass these into your **Buttons** and render accordingly. Specifically, you need to pass the 'active' prop to the Buttons (see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wzq0941wol).

```
<Button.Group>
  <Button onClick={() => this.click(1)}
     active={this.state.active === 1} >
   One
  </Button>
  <Button onClick={() => this.click(2)}
     active={this.state.active === 2}
  >Two
  </Button>
</Button.Group>
```

and then your click handler just saves the state:

```
click(val) {
    this.setState({ active: val });
  }
```

To integrate this with your Answers class above, you could do something like this:

```
export class Answers extends Component {
  render() {
    const selected = this.props.selected;
    return (
      <>
        <Button active={selected === "Never"} data-key="Never">Never</Button>
        <Button active={selected === "Occassionally"} data-key="Occassionally">Occassionally</Button>
        <Button active={selected === "Often"} data-key="Often">Often</Button>
        <Button active={selected === "Very Often"} data-key="Very Often">Very Often</Button>
        <Button active={selected === "Always"} data-key="Always">Always</Button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

and then in your Section class:

```
            <Button.Group widths="5" onClick={this.handleClick} style={styles}>
                <Answers selected={this.state.que1} style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray' }} />
            </Button.Group>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to fit your current scenario. this.state.active was to demonstrate how it could be done - use active={selected... - and no you don't need to add onClick handlers since you are already doing that (and Im assuming it works ok)

Comment: Ok it's working but user navigate back to this page from another page then again it's losing state.

Comment: ok - thats another question entirely - please post separate question and mark as correct